# Pymongo forEach formatting

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can I format a forEach function so that it can rest on multiple lines without causing a syntax error? Something like

```
self.request.db.myCollection.find().forEach( 
    function(u) { 
       u.forSong = self.request.db.song.find_one({}, {'_id': 1})
       self.request.db.save(u)
     })
```

Comment: Have you tried trailing backslashes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To pass javascript code in from Python, you need to wrap it in a [`bson.Code`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/code.html) object, since otherwise Python itself (rather than PyMongo) will try to parse it. This gives you:

```
import bson
self.request.db.myCollection.find().forEach(bson.Code( '''
    function(u) { 
       u.forSong = self.request.db.song.find_one({}, {'_id': 1})
       self.request.db.save(u)
     }'''))
```

But the fact that you're using `self` in there makes it look like you want to use Python code there, not javascript code. From the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor), it looks like the Cursor object returned from `find` implements Python's Sequence protocol - meaning you ought to just be able to use a regular Python loop instead of `forEach` (which the docs seem to say that PyMongo doesn't implement anyway):

```
for u in self.request.db.myCollection.find():
   u.forSong = self.request.db.song.find_one({}, {'_id': 1})
   self.request.db.myCollection.save(u)
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass any mongo command without having Python doing anything in the background, you need to use eval. So your example needs to be called this way:

```
self.request.db.eval('db.myCollection.find().forEach( 
    function(u) { 
       u.forSong = db.song.find_one({}, {"_id": 1});
       self.request.db.save(u);
     })')
```