# backup collection using pymongo

Tags: pymongo

since eval() and copyTo() have been deprecated from mongodb3+. I'm looking at a way to take a back up of collection using something like

db.collection.find().forEach(function(d){db.collection_backup.save(d)})

I'm basically looking for help on these two.

1: How do I run any .js file on Mongo with PyMongo. Example:
mongo < something.js and the js file can have some specific set of commands or functions.
2: how do I run my above code to take the backup of collections across 100s' of databases using pymongo

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyMongo does *not* include a feature for executing a .js file on the server.

An aggregation pipeline with $out is an efficient way to copy a collection. If you want to back up the "role" collection, for example, in each database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
for db_name in client.database_names():
    db = client[db_name]
    if 'role' in db.collection_names():
        print('copy %s.role' % db_name)
        db.role.aggregate([{'$match': {}}, {'$out': 'role_backup'}])
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse for the reply. My requirement here is to take a backup of collections reather than db. Let me be more clear. I have a mongodb-3.2.4 replicaset which has 100 databases like client1, client2, client3.... upto client100. Each client db has a collection called `role` in it. Our application is going to make some changes to the collection, so to be on a safer side, I have to take the backup of all collections before the application code is changed. I have a function like I described above to take the backup. I need to run it and take the back up of the collection across all dbs'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858689/pymongo-foreach-formatting?noredirect=1&lq=1 may be something similar to what has been answered here by @Ivc . Let me see if I can find any pointers.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Jesse, this command is creating temporary collection in 3.2.4 and there's a chance of losing the data if the step down happens. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23274 any other alternative.

Comment: Seems like you should upgrade to 3.2.5!